# virtualbox 6.1: no more dual display

Tags: virtualbox

I have been using virtual box 5 for a while, worked fine, always had dual display. Updated to 6.1 no more 2nd display. The display count is set to 2 in the settings. In view menu of the machine try to enable the second view, does not give any effect.

Comment: As the virtualbox tag states: *Notice: Only programming-related questions are on-topic* Please delete this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this same problem.  After much fiddling with reinstallation and configuration, reverting back to an earlier version of VirtualBox was the only solution I found.

Comment: Ah.., unbelievable. How can they make a major release with such a flaw. Thanks anyway.

Comment: To follow up:  I was offered an update to 6.0.16-135674 which does still work and is probably the last of the 6.0 series.

Comment: To follow up again, an update to 6.1.4-136177 still sees this problem if multiple CPUs are disabled.  If multiple CPUs are enabled, then (motherboard) I/O APIC must be enabled and I think that breaks things.

Comment: 6.0.18-136238 has come out, and this seems to be the best working version for my problems:  multiple monitors, multiple CPUs, no audio stuttering bug.  Remember to update your guest addictions (possibly twice!)

Comment: 32bit Debian:  If the graphics controller is set to VMSVGA, then the second monitor will not work.  VBoxSVGA resolves this.